# Difference between a uuencoded file using Java and Python

Tags: java, python, uuencode

I've to translate a Python code to a Java code and I've got a problem with uuencoding.

Python function:

```
 import uu
 uu.encode("input_file", "output_file")
```

Java function:

```
 MimeUtility.encode(new FileOutputStream(output_file_path), "uuencode");
 stream.write(Files.readAllBytes(input_file));
```

The result of these functions should be the same uuencoded file, but it is not (they are almost the same). Java uuencoded file is with 2 bytes bigger than the Python.

Where would the problem be?

Edit:
An extra byte is added after the name tag (`<begin><mode><name>`) and a byte after end tag (`<end>`)

Comment: Is the encoded text the same save for those two bytes? Do they preface or trail?

Comment: An extra byte is added after the name tag (<begin><mode><name>) and a byte after end tag (<end>)

Comment: note that the whole [`uu` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/uu.py) is less than 200 lines in Python 3.7, so should be pretty easy to modify if you care about it doing something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a line break issue.

MIME has always been defined to use CR+LF as terminators, but if using raw encoding such as Python, it is using only LF on Linux. See [RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-2.10)

```
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/uu.py

79         out_file.write('begin %o %s\n' % ((mode&0777),name))
```

You should set the `os.linesep` system variable to `'\r\n'` so it writes CR+LF line breaks.

Comment: To confirm this, can you look at the hex dump?